# How to leave some RAM aside for virtual terminal?

Tags: freeze, ram, virtual-console

I want to leave some RAM aside for a virtual terminal that is accessed through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.

When my computer froze, I tried to switch over to it to kill some processes, but it was not being brought up, so maybe it shares RAM with the graphical login.

How can I leave some RAM aside for it?
And how much RAM would be enough for this task?

Comment: see: superuser.com: [Is there a way to reserve some RAM for a process to prevent it from becoming unresponsive?](https://superuser.com/questions/1026708/is-there-a-way-to-reserve-some-ram-for-a-process-to-prevent-it-from-becoming-unr)